# How to count all of the windows in a frame?

Tags: elisp, window, frames

Just as the question stated, I would like a function that would count of the windows that are currently being shown in that frame.

So this:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|              |             |
|              |             |
|  *scratch*   | *Messages*  |
|              |             |
|              |             |
|              |             |
+--------------+-------------+
|           *Help*           |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

Would return `=> 3`

I started a function below:

```
(defun count-windows ()
  "Count how many buffers are currently being shown."
  (interactive)
)
```

Comment: Do you mean the number of windows, or the number of unique buffers visible in windows?

Comment: In the example given, you have 3 windows showing 3 different buffers.  If, say, 2 of those windows were showing `*scratch*`, would you want the function to return 3 or 2?

Comment: @Dan, sorry for the misunderstanding, and I would the function to return 3 still.

Comment: Got it -- answer below gives both options: it looks like you want the simpler one (`count-windows`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you mean the number of *windows* regardless of which buffers are showing, then: `(length (window-list))` will do it.  Better still, you can just use the existing `(count-windows)` function.

If you want to count the number of *unique buffers* visible in windows on the frame, then you can use:

```
(length (cl-delete-duplicates (mapcar #'window-buffer (window-list))))
```

(Note that `window-list` can also take an optional FRAME argument if you want something other than the selected frame.)

Wrapping the latter in your function call will give you:

```
(defun count-unique-visible-buffers (&optional frame)
  "Count how many buffers are currently being shown.  Defaults to
selected frame."
  (length (cl-delete-duplicates (mapcar #'window-buffer (window-list frame)))))
```

(Note that this function assumes you have loaded `'cl-lib`.  As per comments, you could use `delete-dups` in place of `cl-delete-duplicates` if you want to avoid `cl-lib`.)

Comment: +1 Great answer! The only info that's missing is that `cl-delete-duplicates` needs to be made available by `require`ing `cl`.

Comment: Good catch, thanks.  I've edited the answer to mention it.

Comment: Do you know a way or a function that doesn't require you to load `'cl-lib`?

Comment: Actually, yes: it turns out the [`delete-dups`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html) would also work, and doesn't require 'cl-lib.